# How does Facebooks new fullscreen photo viewer work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

We're used to using websites like youtube in full screen, but now Facebook offers this for its image gallery. What is Facebook doing to allow full screen image browsing, that seems to use normal hmtl coding?

Comment: what's with all the downvotes? I'm curious about this fact too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the non-standard [Fullscreen API](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen).

In theory (from an article linked from the page I linked to above):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myId");  
if (elem.requestFullScreen) {  
  elem.requestFullScreen();  
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();  
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
  elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's more or less it..

Here is an actual working example to work off of..
all html5.. [DOCUMENTATION](http://css.dzone.com/articles/pragmatic-introduction-html5)

the demo link is down the page a little ways...
[DEMO](http://robnyman.github.com/fullscreen/)

Answer (score 0):

Johndyer has share a [plugin for jQuery](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/#comment-110362) that work with native fullscreen api. It work great with Chrome/Firefox/Safari right now and maybe Internet Explorer and Opera in future.

Furthur, there is [some trick](http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript) that make the api above to work with current version of Internet Explorer.

Opera is not support currently.

Using the API is easy:

```
 <button onclick="fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(document.documentElement)" />
```

[Demo1 from Johndyer](http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/)

[Demo 2 that's limited working with Internet Explorer](http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript)

https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/ is a "crossbrowser" script (for browsers which are able to use fullscreen)